# Bi directional file transfer like Xender

Tags: android, p2p, file-transfer, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I tried my hands at `WifiP2pManager`. I discovered that we can create groups(group owner ie `config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;`) and peers can transfer data to this group owner.

I would like to know if we can achieve something like xender using wifi direct wherein we can create a group and the group owner can transfer data to all its connected peers.(One device sending to many peers)

I used google sample and [this link](https://github.com/anuj7sharma/WiFiDIrectDemo) as reference. Any help on how i can achieve this would be appreciated.